# Embed Win32 App inside a UWP App

Tags: uwp, windows-10

In my scenario i need to embed (i.e open within) a Win32 GUI app in UWP GUI app or vice versa.

I can able to launch as separate application. But i wants to open within the application.

Is it possible? If yes please explain how to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my scenario i need to embed (i.e open within) a Win32 GUI app in UWP GUI app or vice versa

For extend the Win32 GUI with UWP GUI, which is impossible currently. You need to create a Windows app package for your desktop application by using the [Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) firstly. Details for how to do you could reference [Package an app using the Desktop App Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter). And then you could [Extend your desktop application with modern UWP components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extend). This guide contains details about how to do and a sample.

But if you mean you want to display the Win32 and UWP UI inside the same window, unfortunately it is impossible currently. Details please check this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784680/in-wpf-control-display-a-uwp-app).

Comment: Hi Sunteen, Is it possible to embed a UWP app inside another UWP app?

Comment: @PrayerlinRex, yes, you could use `LaunchForResult`:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results